# jQuery UI Timepicker

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas quisiera que por defecto me muestre la hora actual, no sé cómo hacer, tengo la grilla con la hora y minuto con PM/AM para elegir, si hago click en "Now", si me da la hora actual. Pero yo quisiera que en el input ya se muestre por defecto la hora actual sin hacer click. El formato que me muestra es "08:35 AM"

```
<div>
   <label for="hora">Hora</label>
   <?php echo form_input('hora',$venta->hora, ' id="hora" class="timepicker" size="6"'); ?> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.timepicker').timepicker ({ 
          showPeriod: true 
        , showNowButton: true
        , showCloseButton: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: y si agregas tu código?

Comment: hola, ahi lo agregue :)

Comment: Estas usando codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar la hora actual en el timepicker puedes hacerlo directamente con javascript y jquery, suponiendo que usas la libreria timepicker para jquery a continuacion te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var today = new Date(); // for now
var hour = today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes();

$('#hora').timepicker({ 'step': 1, timeFormat: 'H:i:s A' }).val(hour);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />
  <title>timepicker</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <label for="hora">Hora</label>
   <input id="hora" class="timepicker" type="text">
</div> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Juan, ahora cuando el minuto es menor a 10, quisiera q me aparezca con el cero adelante, porque por ejemplo m muestra 18:5, me gustaria q muestre 18:05, gracias por tu aporte :)

Comment: No se por que te sucede eso, el ejemplo funciona correctamente a mi me muestra 18:05, sin embar acabo de hacer un edición a la respuesta para que pruebes así, si la respuesta te sirvio considera marcarla como solucion a tu problema, asi mejoran las estadisticas del sitio, y otros usuarios pueden encontrar util tu pregunta.